# Replace <picture> src onmouseover with animated webp

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<picture>` element with 2 images. An `.avif` image and a `.jpg` fallback.

```html
<picture id="mouse-event" onmouseover="this.src='/animated.webp'">
    <source type="image/avif" srcset="/sm.avif">
    <img src="/sm.jpg">
</picture>
```

When I move my mouse over the `<picture>` element, I want to replace the the shown image with an animated `.webp` (smiliar to youtube thumbnail hover).

I have tried putting `onmouseover`on the picture element but that didn't work.

Also I tried replacing the src with javascript without success:

```js
document.getElementById("mouse-event").src = "/animated.webp";
```

(Just for fun I added the onmouseover event to the img tag. That works, but only if I disable browser support for .avif so that the jpg is shown.)

How can I achieve an image replacement onmouseover with a picture element so that avif/jpg fallback is still possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `img` element's `src` or the `source` element's `srcset`, not the `picture` element's `src`.

For example

```html
<picture id="mouse-event" onmouseover="doMouseover()">
  <source type="image/avif" srcset="/sm.avif">
  <img id="theImage" src="/sm.jpg">
</picture>

<script>
  function doMouseover() {
    document.getElementById("theImage").src = "/animated.webp";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This would only change the <img> src, but on browsers with avif support, the avif is shown. So the src replacement is not visible. https://jsfiddle.net/bt9v52r4/

Comment: OH yeah, you were right. I had to replace the <source> also with srcset. https://jsfiddle.net/k3tbmsjc/